# Invariant violation caused by await

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here is the render in a `Group` component in react native app (0.59):

```
render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
            style={styles.selectionList}
            data={this.state.activeGroups} 
            renderItem={({item, section, index}) => {
                return (
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <View style={[styles.content, {backgroundColor: colors[index % colors.length]}]}>
                            <View style={styles.leftIcon}>
                                {/* <Image style={styles.image} source={{}}/> */}
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this._onPress(item.id)}} >
                                    <Text style={styles.item} key={item.id}>{ item.name}</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity> 
                            </View>                                             
                            <View>
                                {this.displayMember(item)}  //<<<===cause Invariant violation error
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )
            }}                                           
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
        />
    );
```

To test, the `displayMember` is simplified and defined as below:

```
async displayMember(item) {
   let myself = await helper._getUser(this.state.token.password, this.state.token.username); //<<== removed this line makes the error disappear
   return null;
};
```

The code caused the error of invariant violation:

[image]

If the `let myself = await helper._getUser ...` (the helper._getUser pulls the current user info from the server and has been fully tested) is removed from the `displayMember`, then the error disappears and the component is rendered successfully. Why this `await` causes the error and how to fix?

Comment: what is `helper._getUser` ?

Comment: This is a method to pull user info from the server and has been fully tested

Comment: Why run getting server information in a view?

Comment: The error is due to, you are trying to render an object `{this.displayMember(item)}`. Just do this `{JSON.stringify(this.displayMember(item))}`, and you will see it is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, it is hard to answer with an exact solution.  Also not sure if the user's data is relative to the item or not (maybe why it was nested in the view? but item was not used?).  Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

1. Call `this.displayMember(item)` in `componentDidMount`.  Then call setState with the response, ie `setState({userData: response})`
2. As mentioned by ravibagul91, you are referencing an object.  If using stringify, place in a `<Text>` element, otherwise reference a property of the object.
3. The following is not a working example:

```html
export default class TestClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    this.state = {
      token: {
        username: '',
        password: '',
      },
      userData: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    // ...do something to get token data named 'retreivedTokenData'
    this.setState({token: {...retreivedTokenData}});
    this.displayMember();
  }

  _onPress = (itemId) => {
    // ...do something here
  }

  displayMemeber = async () => {
    let userData = await helper._getUser(this.state.token.password, this.state.token.username);
    this.setState({userData});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={styles.selectionList}
        data={this.state.activeGroups} 
        renderItem={({item, section, index}) => {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={[styles.content, {backgroundColor: colors[index % colors.length]}]}>
                        <View style={styles.leftIcon}>
                            {/* <Image style={styles.image} source={{}}/> */}
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this._onPress(item.id)}} >
                                <Text style={styles.item} key={item.id}>{ item.name}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity> 
                        </View>                                             
                        <View>
                            {this.state.userData}
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        }}                                           
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      />
    );
  }
}

// ...styles...
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem lies here.

```
async displayMember(item) {
   let myself = await helper._getUser(this.state.token.password, this.state.token.username); //<<== removed this line makes the error disappear
   return null;
};
```

While the flatlist is rendering it can't be await or in async. Async means what is rendering in background. When the flatlist renders it finds the result as empty or it fails to get the value. Try using :

```
  async componentDidMount(){
   await this.displayMember(//whatever item);
  }
```

Then show the data in flatlist by reading it from state.